# Java - Representing three valued Logic as datatype

Tags: java, logic

For a Lecture in Universtity I have to write a three-valued logic (true, false, unknown) in Java. I have this so far:

```
public class TriLogic {


    public enum Logic {
        TRUE, FALSE, UNKNOWN
    }


    public Logic Disj(Logic op1, Logic op2){

    }

    public Logic Neg (Logic op1){

    }

    public Logic Conj(Logic op1,Logic op2){

    }
}
```

Note: It's not within our task to actually implement the logic in the functions.

This class theoretically should represent the three valued logic with the 3 method of negation, disjunction and conjunction. Yet I am not 100% sure if its correct. Therefor I'd like to hear a second opinion. Would this work?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: I am using Eclipse and it seems that (even do I've set it to use JDK 1.8) it is not recognizing enum.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Also, assuming this is a typo, but you're missing a semicolon after `UNKNOWN`

Comment: Enumerations don't need a semi-colon after the last element; the Logic enum declaration is correct.

Comment: @Dave Well, that's only if you have nothing else in the enum. If you define methods/fields/constructors, the semicolon is required.

Comment: What I mean is that Eclipse is telling me in this case that "enum" is a reserved keyword. It doesn't seem to recognize that I want to use enum. So I am not sure if I am using enums correct or if it's eclipse fault.

Comment: It is. You're on the right track to using enums correctly one way, but I think there's a more interesting way to do this, that I'm going to post soon

Comment: function names that begin with a capital letter look odd.

Comment: @tgkprog I know. Yet I have to use capital letter to match it with the exercise sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is do away with the entire `TriLogic` class and have your methods in the `enum` itself:

```
public enum Logic {
    TRUE {
        @Override
        public Logic disj(Logic op) {}

        @Override
        public Logic neg() {}

        @Override
        public Logic conj(Logic op) {}
    },
    FALSE {
        @Override
        public Logic disj(Logic op) {}

        @Override
        public Logic neg() {}

        @Override
        public Logic conj(Logic op) {}
    },
    UNKNOWN {
        @Override
        public Logic disj(Logic op) {}

        @Override
        public Logic neg() {}

        @Override
        public Logic conj(Logic op) {}
    };

    public abstract Logic disj(Logic op);

    public abstract Logic neg();

    public abstract Logic conj(Logic op);

}
```

Yes, it's a lot more typing. It works, though. I'd actually prefer this, as you don't need to do if-else checks and/or switches for the logic methods, and it could be more convenient to use too (e.g. `TRUE.neg().conj(FALSE);`, for example). Your call. You could also add static methods to operate on two `Logic` values, but that would be optional. In fact, now that I think about it, the static methods would be *really* easy to implement:

```
public static Logic disj(Logic op1, Logic op2) { return op1.disj(op2);}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work, but it's not quite 'correct'. Your `TriLogic` class should have a `final Logic` immutable member variable, and the methods should have one-less argument; the result of each operation would be the TriLogic's variable combined with the methods argument. (`Neg` would be the simple negation of the variable). This would allow you to do

```
Logic false = true.Neg();
```

Constructor for this class left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Notice how the methods take `Logic` parameters... I actually believe that this class would work better as a static utility class.

Comment: I did notice that, that's why I've suggested my improvement. They should either be static (bit crap) or the class re-factored to use my suggestion.

Comment: What's wrong with static methods? I think if you were to go your suggested path, you should do away with the entire `TriLogic` class and stick the methods *inside* the enum, because constructors for a class with only three possible states would be pretty pointless.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer yet I assume that it will be past the goal they want us to achieve with this excerise. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @user3580294; I agree actually, it should be a private enum within TriLogic, and the three possible states reflected by public constants.